# Frame height prints 0

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, uikit

As the question states, when I tried to set an image view inside a UIView class, to have a corner Radius of its frame height divided by 2, it wasn't working, so I decided to print the frame height and it was 0.

The height or width for every view in this class prints 0 I don't know why... Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Did you add views with self.view.addSubView(yourView)

Comment: @MatGrlt since the class its a UIView I only wrote addSubview(view)

Comment: Where do you instantiate your subview's frame?

Comment: @MatGrlt In the override init method I set the image view anchors, but didnt set a frame explicitly... The frame passed down by this override is also 0

Comment: @MatGrlt Maybe the problem relies that I passing down a view by parameters, I want to add like a personalized message view. That itself its only a blank UIView, but this object receives another view, that is replaces the old blank UIView with the one passed down by parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. When calling the UI View class i wasn't passing by parameter the actual frame of this view. So when this class initializer was executed the frame was always 0.

Answer (score 0):

By default a view will have no size whatsoever. You have to set some sort of constraints or the view's frame.

**1. Constraints:** 
When setting constraints in `viewDidLoad()`, the view will not instantly gain a size. In order to read the size, you'll have to read it in another function called `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. This function is called after all views were laid out. Here is an example where the view will gain the size of its parent view:

```
    var newView:UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newView = UIView()

        newView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(newView!)

        newView!.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        newView!.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        newView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        newView!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        print(newView!.frame)
    }
```

**2. Frame:** By setting the views frame directly, you can instantly read its size. Here is an example where the view's frame is set to the same bounds as its parent view:

```
    var newView:UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newView = UIView()

        newView?.frame = view.bounds

        newView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(newView!)

        print(newView!.frame)
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that I am inside a UIView, so these methods your talking about are not available for me.

Comment: But u surely have some sort of `UIViewController`? Create a function in the `UIView` that is called in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` that sets up the corner radius.

Comment: I found the problem, in the uiview class initializer i was overriding the frame, so i just pass the frame when calling the uiview in discussion.